# How can I configure a redirection for CredentialExpiredException in web.xml

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, redirect, jaas

I need to redirect to a changePassword page whenever the credentials have expired.
My login component throws a CredentialsExpiredException when it detects that the credentials have expired. So far so good.

I wanted to configure the redirection in web.xml like this:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type> 
    javax.security.auth.login.CredentialExpiredException
  </exception-type>
  <location>/protected/template/passwordChange.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But the redirection does not happen. Instead, if I try with ViewExpiredException it works this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
</exception-type>
    <location>/protected/template/passwordChange.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem is that ViewExpiredException gets generated for everything from a Blocked account to invalid credentials, so it does not work for what I need.

Can someone provide some light towards how can I achieve this redirection for CredentialExpiredException that has been thrown in the login component?

This are my settings:
 - JAAS
 - Tomcat7, Java7, JSF2

I understand there are other options to achieve this, like using a filter. I just think this would be a cleaner way to solve the situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So CredentialExpiredException gets wrapped in ViewExpiredException? Or does VEE happen later in the same request? Post the exceptions stacks. Maybe you need http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter

Comment: Seems like it gets wrapped or replaced in some way. Tried your suggestion with no luck. I am was curious why I cant forward the request when I get CredentialExpiredException in JAAS to some other location. I guess the solution I have is solving this configuring a filter.

Comment: At the end I decided to implement this with a filter, rather than just mapping it in web.xml. Im still interested on why I was not able to implemented the way described in the question, if somebody know the reason I will really appreciate.